# Mask 'unmasking' for some frames

Tags: masking, movie-clip-editor

I have a mask that applies to an entire video clip - with a few key frames.

For some reason some rendered frames omit the mask completely.  After investigating, the output of the mask node in compositing is to mask absolutely nothing.

There are no key frames around the problem frames.

Below is the mask output of frames 9 and 10 in the composite.  As you can see 10 masks nothing, where 9 has the 'key hole' mask.

Frame 9:
[image: 'Keyhole' matte]

Frame 10:
[image: Matte is gone!]

Comment: Hi. Please add images using the built-in uploader: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi also, if possible try to take screen shots with a better resolution. These images are very hard to read.

Comment: Updated with the built in uploader.  As for the resolution, the nodes aren't really part of the issue so far as I can tell.  It'l the matte output that seems to be broken.  I was having issues with frame 19, then I removed some keyframes for the matte, and the problem went away... and then came back on frame 10.